# R- ddply with loop to iterate over each row

Tags: r, function, loops, plyr

I need to get history of each row.
If my table is:

```
aa<-data.frame(tel=c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3), hora=c(1,2,4,4,1,1,3,4,1,2), 
               intentos=c(1,5,1,4,9,2,7,8,8,1), contactos=c(0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1))
```

I need to get for each tel a kind of trend variable of "intentos": for instace actual value /previous value, but for each row. created1=c(NA, 5/1, 1/5, 4/1) for first tel.

My wanted table is:

```
    tel hora    intentos    contactos   created1
1   1   1   1   0   NA
2   1   2   5   1   5
3   1   4   1   0   0.2
4   1   4   4   0   4
5   2   1   9   0   NA
6   2   1   2   1   0.222222222
7   2   3   7   0   3.5
8   2   4   8   1   1.142857143
9   3   1   8   0   NA
10  3   2   1   1   0.125
```

I know I can do things like:

```
library(plyr)
ddply(aa, .(tel), mutate, mean_hora=mean(hora), min_hora=min(hora))
```

But how can I also introduce the looping to get the result described?

I tried to create a function to pass to ddply:

```
g<-function (tbl) {x<-data.frame(tbl)
                   for (i in 2:length(tbl) ){ 
                     print(paste0(i-1))
                     print(tbl[i-1])
                        x[i,1]<-                 
                        tbl[i]/tbl[i-1] }
                   return (x)}
```

If I run thiis over a vector, it works.
So I tried to pass it to the ddply function:

```
library(plyr)
ddply(aa, .(tel), mutate, mean_hora=mean(hora), min_hora=min(hora), created1=g(hora))
```

But I get the following error:

> Error: not compatible with STRSXP

My approach (to pass a function to evaluate each vector) was ok?

Comment: For the life of me, I do not understand how you got the 'created1' results that you did. Thus, I cannot write code to do it.

Can you explain what logic you are using to get the responses for 'created1'?

Comment: @AndrewTaylor... read this please: "for instace actual value /previous value, but for each row."

Comment: Your commas "in place of" decimals was throwing me. I now understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
aa %>% 
  group_by(tel) %>% 
  mutate(lagged_intentos=lag(intentos)) %>% 
  mutate(created1=intentos/lagged_intentos) %>% 
  select(-lagged_intentos)



   tel hora intentos contactos  created1
1    1    1        1         0        NA
2    1    2        5         1 5.0000000
3    1    4        1         0 0.2000000
4    1    4        4         0 4.0000000
5    2    1        9         0        NA
6    2    1        2         1 0.2222222
7    2    3        7         0 3.5000000
8    2    4        8         1 1.1428571
9    3    1        8         0        NA
10   3    2        1         1 0.1250000
```

If you want to do this for all other variables in your dataset then:

```
aa %>% 
  group_by(tel) %>% 
  mutate_each(funs(new=./lag(.)))


   tel     hora  intentos contactos
1    1       NA        NA        NA
2    1 2.000000 5.0000000       Inf
3    1 2.000000 0.2000000         0
4    1 1.000000 4.0000000       NaN
5    2       NA        NA        NA
6    2 1.000000 0.2222222       Inf
7    2 3.000000 3.5000000         0
8    2 1.333333 1.1428571       Inf
9    3       NA        NA        NA
10   3 2.000000 0.1250000       Inf
```

Or, if only a subset of variables:

```
aa %>% 
  group_by(tel) %>% 
  mutate_each(funs(new=./lag(.)),hora,intentos)


   tel     hora  intentos contactos
1    1       NA        NA         0
2    1 2.000000 5.0000000         1
3    1 2.000000 0.2000000         0
4    1 1.000000 4.0000000         0
5    2       NA        NA         0
6    2 1.000000 0.2222222         1
7    2 3.000000 3.5000000         0
8    2 1.333333 1.1428571         1
9    3       NA        NA         0
10   3 2.000000 0.1250000         1
```

Unfortunately, I think it is a current bug in dplyr that it overwrites the variables with the mutated variables. You can add them back in with:

```
aa %>% 
  group_by(tel) %>% 
  mutate_each(funs(new=./lag(.)),hora,intentos) %>% 
  cbind(aa,.) %>% 
  data.frame %>% 
  select(-tel.1) 

   tel hora intentos contactos   hora.1 intentos.1 contactos.1
1    1    1        1         0       NA         NA           0
2    1    2        5         1 2.000000  5.0000000           1
3    1    4        1         0 2.000000  0.2000000           0
4    1    4        4         0 1.000000  4.0000000           0
5    2    1        9         0       NA         NA           0
6    2    1        2         1 1.000000  0.2222222           1
7    2    3        7         0 3.000000  3.5000000           0
8    2    4        8         1 1.333333  1.1428571           1
9    3    1        8         0       NA         NA           0
10   3    2        1         1 2.000000  0.1250000           1
```

Comment: yes, that worked, but since I want to create many columns, is it possible to do this with a function used in ddply? Also I get: "Error: could not find function "%>%"" Is this due to the lack of starting a particular library? Thanks

Comment: @GabrielaPlantie, I have updated the code, and you should not be getting that Error if you've loaded the dplyr package.

Comment: ok, this worked, but how can I do it with ddply? or could you explain what is doping %>%?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. This is dplyr. %>% is a piping operator. Please review the documentation for the dplyr and magrittr packages. They should make this all fairly clear.

Comment: Your edit is a completely separate issue from what you originally posted. Your original question, and then some, has been successfully answered. This question should be closed and you should make a new posting with your new question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71723/discussion-between-gabriela-plantie-and-andrew-taylor).

Comment: Ha. I'm making dinner. I really recommend making a new question that only contains your edit.